# How can I convince IE to honor my explicit instructions to make a table column X pixels wide?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-table

Please consider this small but complete chunk of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    span {overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;  }
    td {overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0"  >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap; "><span>column 1</span></td>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap; "><span>column 2</span></td>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap; "><span>column 3</span></td> 
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you render the above in Chrome you'll see the effect I'm looking for.

However render it in IE8 or 9 the width and/or max-width is ignored.

So my question is how do I get IE to simply let me specify the width of a cell explicitly? (It would also be nice if I didn't have to use max-width to get Chrome to behave either).

BTW, I've tried various combinations of table-layout:fixed and using colgroup with cols and all sorts, nothing I've tried convinces IE to do what I'm clearly asking it to explicitly do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try on your `table` styling:

`table {table-layout: fixed; width :0px;}`

You can ditch the `max-width:30px`

You did mention you used `table-layout`, but stating the `width` here does the trick

Comment: Its looking good, so far I've found I can ditch the max-widths and simply set the table width to 0px and all browsers are generating the same result.

Comment: I'm also unsure how this answer is any different to mine

Comment: changing the answer to reflect your comment @AnthonyWJones